# How to compare NSDate to check if dates are within the same week

Tags: swift, nsdate

I have two NSDates. How can I compare them to find out if the dates are within the same week.

I have a system that currently checks if two dates are within the same day and the code for this is below:

```
if calan.compareDate(datee, toDate: now, toUnitGranularity: .CalendarUnitDay) == .OrderedSame {
    transactionsToday.addObject(transaction)
}else{
    println("No transactions today")
}
```

Which UnitGranularity would I use to check if the two dates share the same week?

Comment: Do you want to check if two dates are within the same week or within one week of each other. Should a `saturday` and the next `tuesday` be considered true (it is within one week of each other) or should it return false cause they are in different weeks

Answer (score 13):

```
if calan.compareDate(datee, toDate: now, toUnitGranularity: .CalendarUnitWeekOfYear) == .OrderedSame {
    transactionsToday.addObject(transaction)
}else{
    println(“No transactions this week")
}
```

The same way you now use `.CalendarUnitDay` You can also use `.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear`

EDIT:
If ou want to check if the date is within a week instead of in the same week you could get the last- and nextWeekDate

```
let lastWeekDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)!
```

of course next week would be

```
let nextWeekDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, value: 1, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)!
```

You could then see if your current date is between these 2 dates

Comment: As far as I know, the compareDate() works correctly even across "year boundaries".

Comment: @Martin let today = `NSDate()
let nextWeek = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitYear, value: 1, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)!

let weekOfYear1 = calendar!.component(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, fromDate: today)
let weekOfYear2 = calendar!.component(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, fromDate: nextWeek)

if (weekOfYear1 == weekOfYear2) {
        println("Same week")
} else {
    println(“Other week")
}` Years are not taken into consideration, if you take the same date next year it will be considered the same week

Comment: What I meant is that `calan.compareDate(datee, toDate: now, toUnitGranularity: .CalendarUnitWeekOfYear)` works correctly ...

Comment: The code that you mentioned does indeed work correctly, though extracting the week of year components fails the test

Comment: For Swift3, avoid using NSCalendar. Use Calendar instead. For example: `let lastWeekDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: -1, to: Date())`

Answer (score 1):

If you use Gregorian calendar, you can use calculate week of year and get year of those 2 dates then compare.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

let date1 = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
let date2 = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -10*24*60*60) //10 day earlier.

let weekOfYear1 = calendar!.component(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, fromDate: date1)
let weekOfYear2 = calendar!.component(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, fromDate: date2)

let year1 = calendar!.component(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: date1)
let year2 = calendar!.component(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: date2)

if (weekOfYear1 == weekOfYear2
     && year1 == year2
) {
     NSLog("Same week")
} else {
     NSLog("Other week")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for dates of the same week and different years, as can be December 31, 2015 and January 1, 2016. But is a good approach.

Comment: You can just add first the check if 2 dates is same year or not. If it's not the same then return "false", if it's the same year then continue to check with this code.

Comment: Yes, I use your method for dates within the same year because it is the faster way. If not, I search for the last of the two dates to compare, then I search for the first day of the week and then I check if the first of the two dates is after the first day of the week. It may seem a little bit complex but I already had methods to get the first day of a week.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift5**

I wrote a little extension which makes this process a little easier:

```
extension Date {
    func isTheSame(_ component: Calendar.Component, as date: Date) -> Bool {
        return Calendar.current.compare(self, to: date, toGranularity: component) == .orderedSame
    }
}
```

You can then simply do something like this:

```
if firstDate.isTheSame(.week, as: secondDate) {
    // Both dates are the same week
} else {
    // Dates are different weeks
}
```

(works for any category, eg: .day, .month, .year etc)